# XCode - find every use of an object of a certain class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

Is there a way to search my project to find places I've used an object of a certain class.

I want to change all dates to localised dates in my app. I can search for the keyword "date" which should be reliable, but it turns up loads of other results such as "update" and similar keywords.

So, I would prefer to be able to find where I've used an object of class NSDate. Is there a reliable way to do this? I know I can search for the keyword "NSDate" but I may not have always used that - e.g. in a method that returns an NSDate I may call it like this:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self theDate]];
```

I'm sure this probably isn't possible, but I thought I'd ask on the offchance! :)

Thanks!

Comment: Is this functionality still missing after so many years? lol

Answer (score 0):

You can select that keyword, e.g function name, class name, variable name, etc, and go to the declarations, uses, and every place where it is, by clicking the little arrow button, which appears on it after selecting the whole keyword.

Answer (score 0):

You can click the name of the object for eg. date of NSDate class in your case and there will be an arrow facing downwards which is clickable. You can click on that and select Edit All in scope from the drop down menu. It will show up that object in that scope in selected grey colored background

Comment: This is just for the current scope though, not throughout the whole project? Or will it do the whole project?

Comment: Yes,unfortunately, you are right that it is for the current scope only. Have to repeat it for each scope.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode on the left most panel.

Select the project.

Go to 3rd tab (show the search navigator).

Search whatever you want to search from the current project.

Even you can replace them.

Another way,

Select the text you want to search.

Right click and "Find selected text in workspace"

Comment: It doesn't search usages, it searches text